# How to print current hierachy path for the current entity/architecture?

Tags: vhdl

Here's what I can do in Verilog:

```
module xyz();
    initial begin
        $display("%m <= current module path");
    end
endmodule
```

How to do this in VHDL?  I heard that the 'INSTANCE_NAME attribute might be what I'm looking for, but how to use it to get the full path to the entity/architecture as a string?

```
    -- Proc1'PATH_NAME = ":e:a:proc1[natural,integer]:"
    -- Proc1'INSTANCE_NAME = ":e:a:proc1[natural,integer]:"
```

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use std.textio.all;
use std.env.stop;
entity test_stop is
    port(
        clk :in  std_logic
    );
end entity;
architecture sim of test_stop is
    procedure print(s: in string) is
        variable L :line;  
    begin
        write(L, string'(s & LF));
        writeline(output, L);
        flush(output);
    end procedure;
begin
    process
    begin    
        print(entity'INSTANCE_NAME & "<== need full hierarchy to this module here");    
        wait;
    end process;
                            
end architecture;
```

Comment: Did you run this?   What did it print?  Does "entity" work?   I have always used the entity name, here "test_stop"

Comment: [The reserved word entity isn't a named entity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akdlB.jpg). That produces: `:test_stop_testbench(foo):dut@test_stop(sim): <== need full hierarchy to this module here`

Answer (score 0):

The part before the apostrophe (the prefix of an attribute name) cannot be a keyword `entity`, but it has to be a named entity, e.g., a VHDL entity, a process label, etc.

See the LRM (IEEE Std 1076-2008), chapter **16.2.5 Predefined attributes of named entities** for more details.

In your specific case, the attribute `'path_name` is probably the best alternative to the Verilog `%m`.

Example:

The following code

```vhdl
report_p : process
begin
  report report_p'simple_name;
  report report_p'instance_name;
  report report_p'path_name;
  wait;
end process;
```

would produce the following console output when located in the architecture `rtl` of the entity `dut` instantiated as `dut_i` in the architecture `behav` of the top level entity `tb`:

```
# ** Note: report_p
#    Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /tb/DUT_I
# ** Note: :tb(behav):dut_i@dut(rtl):report_p:
#    Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /tb/DUT_I
# ** Note: :tb:dut_i:report_p:
#    Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /tb/DUT_I
```